# How to smarten up a dumb Windows command prompt?

Tags: command-line

To put it simple and short - I start my Windows command prompt from *Win-R*, then *cmd*, from several shortcuts with different enviromental variables, and from inside some editors (don't know how they start it).

Now, I need to set *set term=* in every of them cmds, without doing it down manually every time. Is there a way?

Are there some *global* options of cmd somewhere in the registry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably referring to [environment variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable).

The environment is inherited by each process from its parent. In Windows, the first environment is established by the logon process. So, if you launch any editor or other program, it will inherit from Windows its environment, add to it its own variables, and will pass them all to any cmd child that it launches on its own account.

If you want *term* to be always present in any cmd process that is ever launched on your login, go to Control Panel / System / Advanced / Environment variables. There you have the choice of setting *term* for you own logon or for the system (meaning every process launched with or without login).

If you are looking for a better GUI than that offered by Windows, the freeware [Rapid Environment Editor](http://www.rapidee.com/en/about) is an excellent option.

Comment: Good grief. This sounds stupid but before I asked the question, I looked and didn't see it there. :( Must've missed it ... late hours, I guess ...

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with `set term`, but you can always set environment variables in the System control panel.

You were probably looking for the `autorun` value in the registry located here:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor
```

And/or:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor
```

This should be a `REG_SZ` or a `REG_EXPAND_SZ` containing a command executable in Command Prompt. You may want to set this to, say `%USERPROFILE%\autorun.bat` to run a series of commands.

Note that the `HKLM` value will be run before the `HKCU` value if both are set.

Source: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779439%28WS.10%29.aspx

Beware of [Link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20071121-00/?p=24433) though.

Answer (score 2):

Install ConEmu.
Native shell, nicer features, and a possibility to do a cool hack over FAR
[image]

Comment: Btw, there is sort of "Autoattach" feature (ConEmu may be started with cmd.exe), and you may attach any console to existing ConEmu instance. I'm great fan of Far Manager, but ConEmu may be used with any shell processor - cmd/powershell/bash/etc.

Comment: @Maximus, I know it is expected to be used with any shell, the answer's idea was to show some console eyecandy too.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend switching to [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/). Take the power of the Unix terminal and plug it into Windows.

Comment: Got a lot of programs which are (so to speak) written for cmd environment, which I need for work. Can't switch. Otherwise, it would be an option.

Comment: @Rook 99% of all DOS programs work in cygwin

Comment: @TheLQ - Not when they have hardcoded paths and depend on DOS commands(some of which I've had to rewrite for cmd, since they were no longer available). Trust me on this one...

Comment: @TheLQ: Who still uses DOS programs nowadays?

Comment: @Joey Rook apparently.

Comment: @TheLQ: they never said that. You might confuse Windows console programs with DOS.

Comment: Windows paths can automatically be converted to Cygwin paths. I believe this is even the default behavior, though you may receive a warning.